# z-index blocking out zoom-in zoom-out for Google map iframe

Tags: html, css, google-maps, iframe, z-index

I'm having a diagonal image which I will use for the complete body background. I have a large space in the image in which I've inserted the google map iframe. However it is not clickable or zoom-in or zoom-out.

```
iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -9999999999;
}
img {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3ef2onLc/1/

Comment: Yo are able to zoom in and out but only outside of the image. Even the transparent parts of an image still act as a layer over top. I would suggest rethinking your design to use two images and ideally completely remove the angles.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is transparent but actually covers the whole map so you will be always clicking the image instead.

One quick solution would be to split the image in two, a left part and an upper part. That way you get a clickable quarter in the bottom right.

The better solution would be to construct the angled parts out of divs with some css. (Helpful: http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/)